# Find all arithmetic functions f satisfying the given relation

Tags: elementary-number-theory, analytic-number-theory

I'm studying the basic analytic number theory material. As of now, I'm stuck with the practice problem.

The problem is following : 
Find all arithmetic functions f satisfying the given relation, f * f = e

I don't know where should I begin. Should I start with the definition of convolution? Except for e, which is Multiplicative identity function, is there any other arithmetic functions for this relation?

Comment: $e $ is a constant.  $f^2= e$.  What functions when squared equal a constant.

Comment: In my question, e(n) is 1 if n = 1, otherwise, e(n) = 0. It is not a constant function. So, I can't come up with f * f = e except for f = e.

Comment: "So, I can't come up with f * f = e except for f = e"  And what makes you think that isn't an acceptable and correct answer?  (I apologize for mistaking e with a constant.  But my hint still stand, what functions when squared equal 1 when n = 1 and when squared equal 0 when n != 1?)

Comment: Does your notation $"*"$ mean multiplication?  As in if f(a) =7 then $f(a)*f(a) = 49$?

Comment: I mean  "∗" as a dirichlet convolution.

Comment: $f*f(n) = \sum_{d|n}f(d)f(n/d)$?

Comment: Yes, it is. So, definitely, $e(n)$ can be $f$ in this problem. I'm looking for the other arithmetic functions.

Comment: $f = -e(n)$ will work too.  $f*f(1) = f(1)f(1)=1$ so $f(1) = \pm 1$.  $p$ prime then $f(p)=f(1)f(p) + f(p)f(1) = \pm 2f(p)$ so $f(p) = 0$. I think you can do a form of induction that if $f*f(n) = 0$ then $f*f(np) = \pm 2f(np) \pm 2 f(p)f(n) \pm2[\sum f(p*m)f(n/m)]$  I haven't quite worked the details out.  If you do strong induction that $f*f(mp) = 0$ for all $m \le n$ then if you can show $f*f(p[n+1])$ that should do it.

Answer (score 1):

"Should I start with the definition of convolution?"

Yes.

$f*g(n)= \sum_{d|n}f(d)g(n/d)$.

So if $f*f(n) =e(n)$ then $f*f(1) = 1$ so $f*f(1) = f(1)f(1) = 1$ so $f*f(1) = \pm 1$.

If $p$ is prime $f*f(p) = f(1)f(p) + f(p)f(1) = \pm 2f(p)=0$ so $f(p) = 0$.

Strong induction.  Suppose we assume  $f(m*p) = 0$ for all $m \le n$.  (we did the base case with $n = 1$) can we show $f((n+1)p)=0$?

$f*f((n+1)p) = f(1)f((n+1)p) + \sum_{d|n}f(d*p)f(n/d) + \sum_{d|n}f(d)f(p*n/d) + f((n+1)p)f(1) = $

$ f(1)f((n+1)p) + \sum_{d|n}0*f(n/d) + \sum_{d|n}f(d)*0 + f((n+1)p)f(1) =$

$\pm 2f((n+1)p)f(1)= 2f((n+1)p)=0$

So $f((n+1)p) = 0$.

Thus for all $n = m*p$ for some prime, which is to say, for all $n \ne 1$ we have $f(n) = 0$.

So $f(1) = \pm 1$ and $f(n) = 0$ if $n \ne 1$.  So $f(n) = \pm e(n)$.